# upgraded to Ubuntu 20, reconfiguring apache2, utterly clueless

Tags: apache2, google-compute-engine, ubuntu-20.04

I upgraded to Ubuntu 20 on my Google Compute vm.

Now apache2 isn't serving stuff up when i hit my server (by external ip) via lynx.

apache2 DOES serve up the default page when i do

```
lynx localhost
```

on my server.

these instructions https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-apache-web-server-on-ubuntu-20-04

say to use

```
ufw app list
```

and choose the one that is the most restrictive Apache profile.

Since I want access via http AND https, i picked Apache Full which the link says "opens both port 80 (normal, unencrypted web traffic) and port 443 (TLS/SSL encrypted traffic)"

ok.  cool.  so far so good.

here's my first question.

`ufw status numbered`

shows me

```
Status: active

     To                         Action      From
     --                         ------      ----
[ 1] 8080                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 2] Apache Full                ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 3] 80/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 4] 443/tcp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 5] 8080 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
[ 6] Apache Full (v6)           ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
[ 7] 80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
[ 8] 443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
[ 9] Apache (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

Is it a problem to have Apache and Apache Full both active?

What about port 8080?

If I have Apache Full active, should i also have separate entries for 80/tcp and 443/tcp?

Should I remove any of that?

Comment: Did you have time to check my answer? It helped you to solve your problem? If yes, Please consider to accept and upvote it. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: i ended up having to rebuild my server

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully installed the **‘Apache Full’** Application on Ubuntu 20.4 virtual machine by following  the [documentation](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-apache-web-server-on-ubuntu-20-04) and I have run the following command for  allowing the traffic.

**`sudo ufw allow 'Apache Full'`**

when I verify with the command **`sudo ufw status`** the output is showing **Active** status as shown in the image.[image].

Since I have installed only Apache Full, the output shows me that the profile has been activated to allow access to the Apache Full web server and web server is started and running successfully by following the commands provided in that documentation.

Since you have both Apache and Apache Full having Allow status and if you want to deny any one of them. You can use the command

**`sudo ufw deny ‘Apache’`**

Check whether you have configured SSL to allow SSL encrypted traffic or any tcp port configuration for 8080,80/tcp,443/tcp.